# show best matches in a mysql tag system

Tags: mysql, function, tags

I'm implementing a system that returns a list of available articles based on tags inserted by the user, so that the user spots the items that match (or loosely match) his criteria. The returned items will be sorted according to how likely is that they are of interest for the user. The front-end collects the tags and use them in a mySQL query (for which I'm asking hel here).

my DB has this structure:

- tags(tag_id, tag_name)
- articles(article_id, some_text)
- articles_tags(article_id,tag_name)

an example:

the user enters the tags: "hard", "sweet", "red". mySQL will return these items, in this order:

1. red_candy  (which is tagged as **hard**, **red**, **sweet**) - so 3/3 tags match
2. red_hammer (which is tagged as **hard**, **red**, dangerous) - so 2/3 tags match
3. stone      (which is tagged as **hard**, gray) - so 1/3 tags match
4. pillow     (which is tagged as soft, white) - 0/3 tags match

Thanks all
AC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
select 
  distinct some_text 
from 
  articles join article_tags on (articles.article_id = articles_tags.article_id ) 
  join tags on (articles_tags.tag_id =  tags.tag_id) 
where 
  tag_name in ("hard", "sweet", "red") 
order by count(tag_id) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

gbejic's answer is perfect.
I was starting writing functions for computing scores and what not, but this is very intuitive and straightforward.
thanks a lot
AC